# compare adjacent rows in R

Tags: r, loops, date, comparison, row

In my dataframe, I have a column "dates" and I would like for R to walk through each row of dates in a loop to see if the date before or after it is within a 3-14 day range, and if not, it's indexed to a list to be removed at the end of the loop.

for example:

```
my_dates <- c( "1/4/2019", "1/18/2019", "4/3/2019", "2/20/2019", "4/5/2019")
```

I would want to remove the entire row containing `2/20/2019` because there is no other date that is within 3-14 days of that date.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a verbose way using `lubridate` and `dplyr`.

```
my_dates <- c( "1/4/2019", "1/18/2019", "4/3/2019", "2/20/2019", "4/5/2019")

library(lubridate); library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(dates = mdy(my_dates)) %>%
  arrange(dates) %>%
  mutate(days_prior  = dates - lag(dates),
         days_before = lead(dates) - dates) %>%
  mutate(closest_day = pmin(days_prior, days_before, na.rm = T)) %>%
  filter(closest_day <= 14)
```

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be between 3 and 14 days, not just less than 14?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to interpret "within 3-14" days, since arguably 1-2 days is "within", aka less than, that range. If you want to cut things that have a closest day on the day or up to two days away, we'd just change to `filter(closest_day >= 3, closest_day <=14)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a bit of `order`ing and `diff`ing:

```
my_dates <- c( "1/4/2019", "1/18/2019", "4/3/2019", "2/20/2019", "4/5/2019")
my_dates <- as.Date(my_dates, format="%m/%d/%Y")

o <- order(my_dates)
d <- abs(diff(my_dates[o]))

my_dates[o[ c(Inf,d) <= 14 | c(d,Inf) <= 14 ]]
#[1] "2019-01-04" "2019-01-18" "2019-04-03" "2019-04-05"
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense. 

I forgot to mention that I'm also interested in doing this by group. I have a group "Patient_ID" and I would like for R to pull out dates not within the 14-day range but only if it is the same patient. For example, if there are two dates, but 1/20/2019 belongs to Patient A and 1/24/2019 belongs to Patient B, I want R to ignore that.

I have the following code: 

`df<-data.table(data_2011_2018$Patient_ID,data_2011_2018$Date_of_Collection)
z = df[ , baseline := Date_of_Collection - shift(Date_of_Collection), by = Patient_ID]`

Comment: @steph.zank - that's probably a separate question which builds on this one. Ideally, you'd need to post again providing a simple example of your `data.table` (in reproducible form) and point back to this question as a resource. It shouldn't be too hard to do from your description, but it would just be easier with a new question / data. Since you're using `data.table` too, there might be totally different approaches which will scale much better to grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way from `outer`, data from [thelatemail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56266119/7964527)

```
s=abs(-outer(my_dates, my_dates, '-'))
my_dates[rowSums(s<=14)>1]
[1] "2019-01-04" "2019-01-18" "2019-04-03" "2019-04-05"
```